# Fade effect on link color

Tags: jquery, css

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({
        color: '#22373A'
    }, 'slow');
}, function(){
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({
        color: '#fe57a1'
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Im using this to change the opacity of elements when hovering, but seems it wont work with color change. Any Ideas or suggestions?

regards
dennym

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/  1st paragraph after *Animation Properties and Values*  *... but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used ...*

Comment: Thanks yoshi this was helpful, finally switched to transition, quite easier :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using CSS transitions instead?

HTML:

```
<a href="#">foo</a>
<a href=#>bar</a>​
```

CSS:

```
html {
  font: 2em/1.5 sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #22373a;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s ease-out; /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
  -moz-transition: color 1s ease-out; /* Firefox 4+ */
  -ms-transition: color 1s ease-out; /* IE10+ */
  -o-transition: color 1s ease-out; /* Opera 10.5+ */
  transition: color 1s ease-out;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #fe57a1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HTDSJ/

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), I don't think `color` works with `animate`. I'm not sure if you are familiar with color theory but there are multiple ways to go from one point to another on a color wheel. Should it go straight to the next point? Should it travel a concentric ellipse to the next point (which would only have a 50% chance of working)? Should it travel along a linear polar function? It's too ambiguous and for that reason, I think they chose not to implement that. However, there is a [jQuery plugin for this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color).

Comment: Very true, but less compatibility.

Comment: The popular browser are supported if u use all the prefixes... Do u know any browser which has a problem? @